# how to export a local report to a pdf and excel file?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have two web pages, page1.aspx and page2.aspx. In page1, there is a button; in page2, there is a local report (rdlc). When I click the button, it will bring up page2, and exporting the report to a pdf and excel file. If the report is Crystal Report, in the page_load of page2, I can call the function ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType, FileName) to export the report to pdf/excel. But now I am using local report (rdlc), I wonder how do I export it to a pdf/excel.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// References:
/// </summary>
private void RenderReport() {
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
    localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc"); 

    //A method that returns a collection for our report
    //Note: A report can have multiple data sources
    List<Employee> employeeCollection = GetData();

    //Give the collection a name (EmployeeCollection) so that we can reference it in our report designer
    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("EmployeeCollection", employeeCollection);
    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    string reportType = "PDF";
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;

    //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
    //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx
    string deviceInfo =
    "<DeviceInfo>" +
    "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
    "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
    "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
    "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
    "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
    "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
    "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
    "</DeviceInfo>";

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes;

    //Render the report
    renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
        reportType,
        deviceInfo,
        out mimeType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);

    //Clear the response stream and write the bytes to the outputstream
    //Set content-disposition to "attachment" so that user is prompted to take an action
    //on the file (open or save)
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo." + fileNameExtension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview ***not found***

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to remember what contract job this was even at...   I didn't have memory issue, but it would depend on the data.